# Trying to ID a piece, picture included. 1x4 pillar

Tags: part-identification, piece-information

[image]

Looking for the name of the highlighted piece. Any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 7):

That is a

[6070327: Stick Ø3.2 2Mm W/Knob And Tube](https://brickset.com/parts/6070327/stick-%C3%B83-2-2mm-w-knob-and-tube)

[image]